# Is there a way to set the precedence of capturing groups

Tags: regex, regex-group

I want 3 capturing groups (pre/mid/post) that share some characters. All three can match 0 or 1 time, something like this:

```
^(?<pre>[T])?(?<mid>[T][A-Z])?(?<post>[T])?$
```

I am looking for them to match in order: `mid -> pre -> post`. Regex I've posted works for 3/4 letter strings, like `TTT / TTU / TUT`. For two character string `TT`, I would like for group `mid` to be matched - the result is `pre: T, post: T` though. I understand why that's happening - `pre` matches, `mid` doesn't find two character to match, `post` matches.

For `mid` to take precedence I've tried combinations of groups and lazy operators, but most of them resulted in `post` matching before `pre`, like for this example:

```
^(?<pre>[T])??(?<mid>[T][A-Z])?(?<post>[T])?$
```

Is there any way to allow `mid` group to match before `pre`? Can you set some kind of order of matching?

Comment: To match `mid` before `pre`, you are using the lazy `??` correctly. What is wrong with [`^(?<pre>T)??(?<mid>T[A-Z])?(?<post>T)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/XkBUYQ/1)?

Comment: `TTT` matches as `mid + post`, whereas I would like it to match `pre + mid`. With both prefix and suffix having `??` operator, suffix matches first. Only the last lazy operator matches. I couldn't figure out a way to kind of keep the lazy operator within group. Like `((pre)(mid))(post)`

Comment: [`^(?<pre>T)?(?<mid>T[A-Z])?(?<post>T)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/XkBUYQ/2) gives the expected `pre+mid`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But that no longer matches `TT` with only `mid`, like your first attempt did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need any lazy operators - just explicitly group `pre` together with `mid`, so that if `pre` matches then `mid` is required:

```
^(?:(?<pre>T)?(?<mid>T[A-Z]))?(?<post>T)?$
```

<sup>([online demo](https://regex101.com/r/oHWhzp/1))</sup>

Or rather, I think you want to require `mid` to match together with an optional `post`, so that a single `T` input is matched by `pre` only:

```
^(?<pre>T)?(?:(?<mid>T[A-Z])(?<post>T)?)?$
```

<sup>([online demo](https://regex101.com/r/ij6rno/1))</sup>

Comment: The second one is what I was looking for. Seems like I was unnecessarily exploring lazy operators and non-capturing groups were the way. Thanks!